# Mybatis, retrieve oracle field stored as CLOB spring boot

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, spring-mybatis

I have a user stored in oracle DB and one of the fields is stored as a CLOB(a simple Json {"profile": "man"}). I am using Mybatis and i try to retrieve the value.
So i am having:

```
 <resultMap id=userResults>
   <property="details" column="DETAILS" jdbcType="CLOB" 
    javaType="String" 
    typeHandler="org.apache.ibatis.type.ClobTypeHandler"
 </resultMap>
```

and in the POJO:
the field details as a String with getter and setter.

```
class User{
private String name;
private String surname;
private String details;

//getters + setters
}
```

But nothing mapped in the end, even though the row exists in the DB.
The query is:

```
 Select * FROM USER Where USER.id = #{id}
```

Any recommendations?

Comment: is this a typo `javaType=String` (missing double quotes)? Is the query fetching this data actually selecting the DETAILS column? Can you show it?

Comment: Ok, now it seems you have a problem in your query: ` Where is USER.id = #{id}` what "is" is supposed to be here ? the query should be `Select * FROM USER Where USER.id = #{id}` also... always explicitly use all columns fields instead of the `*` in your queries...

Comment: Another thing that I noticed... your Details field in your class has a capital D which may be causing the problem... `private String Details;`

Comment: and you mapped it as `<property="details"`

Comment: Where is this ClobTypeHandler from? In Mybatis [docs](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/apidocs/reference/org/apache/ibatis/type/ClobTypeHandler.html) it is in another package. `org.apache.ibatis.type.ClobTypeHandler`

Comment: Also, take a look at which version of ojdbc driver you are using... I've seem problems in the past about it.

Comment: issue was the ojdbc version by upgrading it, the data came back. thanks for your help. (fixed all the typos)

Comment: Glad to hear that you were able to fix your problem. I will add it as an answer so it may help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some conversation on comments it turns out that the problem was the **Oracle JDBC Driver** after suggesting it and OP upgrading it He was able to make it work.